# Display QuerySet result as Array

Tags: javascript, django

I'm asking a question about my HTML template. I displayed results from some QuerySet with Django and I would like to modify the display user aspect.

I don't know if I can make this kind of things with Django or if JavaScript lets to make that.

**I have an HTML template :**

```
<h2 align="center"> Affichage de toutes les fiches individuelles </align> </h2>

<br></br>

{% block content %}

<h4> Récapitulatif des 10 dernières fiches individuelles créées: </h4>
<ul>
{% for item in identity %}
   <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<h4> Récapitulatif des 10 dernières fiches individuelles créées habitant en France: </h4>
<ul>
{% for item in identity_France %}
   <li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock %}
```

**From this view :**

```
def Consultation(request) :

    identity = Identity.objects.all().order_by("-id")[:10] #Les 10 dernières fiches créées
    identity_France = Identity.objects.filter(country='64').order_by("-id")[:10] #Les 10 dernières fiches où la personne habite en France

    context = {
        "identity" : identity,
        "identity_France" : identity_France,
    }
    return render(request, 'resume.html', context)
```

Is it possible to display the result as an array ? With column, tags for each column etc ... ?

Something like that :

[image]

Thank you !

EDIT :

I found that JQuery makes that : [JQuery Array](http://jquery.iceburg.net/tableEditor/demo.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want inside {% for %} {% endfor %} template tags.
like, you could put your objects inside a table

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Field 1 Name</th>
       <th>Field 2 Name</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   {% for item in identity_France %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.field1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.field2 }}</td>
      <tr>
   {% endfor %}
   <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to display a first line as field name then objects ?

Comment: Yeah I found this HTML command ;) If I want to display array lines, it's with javascript ?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to say as "array lines", can you give me an example?

Comment: I mean drawing an array. Draw all array contours ?

Comment: You can use the forloop.counter inside {%

Comment: I don't know if it answers your question, but I think your talking about forloop.counters, that indexes your list elements inside {% for

Comment: I don't know if it answers your question, but I think your talking about forloop.counters, that indexes your list elements inside {% for %}.

    {% for item in identity_France %}
      {{forloop.counter}} - item.field1 - item.field2
    {% endfor %}

I cant edit my comments :(